# click on link should not trigger parental onclick-event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've got the following code:

```
<div onclick="alert('div event');" style="cursor:pointer">
    some text
    <a href="asd.php" id="link">click</a>
</div>
```

When somebody clicks on the link the javaschipt event is triggered. I want that the event is only triggers if somebody clicks on the text or on the empty space inside the div container; and not if somebody clicks on the link.

Is it possible to call a function when the event is triggered, which checks on which elements the user has clicked. something link

```
onclick="foo(caller);"
```

and

```
function foo(element){
    if(element!='link'){
        alert('yes');   
    }
}
```

Comment: similar [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3838758/select-the-div-but-not-the-link-inside-it-jquery-question)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add a click handler to your link and stop event bubbleing to the parent div. Like this:

```
$('#link').click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function (){
  $('#link').click(function (e){ e.stopPropagation(); /*do other thing*/});
})
```

Answer (score 1):

`OnClick` event you can pass the current object type.
something like

`onclick=foo(this)`

The function foo looks like

```
 function foo(obj) {    
      if(obj.tagName != 'A') {
       alert('Yes')    
      } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the unbind http://api.jquery.com/unbind/