# How to disable a click on a link from also calling a JavaScript event that is hooked up to its parent container?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have a row inside of a table in html that is hooked up to the following JavaScript function:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
        $(window).load(function () {
            $(".clickable").click(function () {

                $(this).next().toggle();

            });
        });
```

This function expands some content directly below this row. I also have a link in this row that is used to click through to another page. It looks like this:

[image]

When I click the link it will quickly expand the content right before it navigates to the page that it is supposed to go to.

How can I change it so that if the link is clicked, it goes to that page ***without*** calling the JavaScript function that expands the extra content?

Comment: possible duplicate of [click on link should not trigger parental onclick-event](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5590944/click-on-link-should-not-trigger-parental-onclick-event) and [Prevent click from child firing parent click event](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6929198/218196) and [Prevent parent container click event from firing when hyperlink clicked](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1997084/218196) and [how to disable parent click](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1398582/218196).

Comment: Sorry yeah this is a dupe, I'll delete.

Comment: Well I guess I can't delete it, but go right ahead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On the link, you want to stop propagation:

```
$('.myNavLink').click(function(e){
   e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Doc link: http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/

**EDIT** As you're having trouble implementing this here is a live example:

http://jsfiddle.net/Vs5B8/

You'll see it has a table with 1 row, with a link in one of the cells:

```
<table>
    <tr class="clickable">
        <td> one </td>
        <td> two </td>
        <td> <a href='http://www.google.co.uk' class="myNavLink"> click me </a> </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I have hooked up a click event on the row:

```
$('.clickable').click(function(){
   alert("row click");
});
```

Therefore a click anywhere in the row will alert `row click`, and even do so when you click the hyperlink. However adding a click event to the `a` to stop propagation will stop this behaviour (ie, not show the alert when clicking the link):

```
$('.myNavLink').click(function(e){
   e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: Thanks, it looks like this is what I want, although I can't seem to get the syntax right with my current function, any suggestions on how to integrate it?