# Select all except specific div and everything inside

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to wrap everything within the body in another div, except one div ID and everything inside it. I tried this:

```
$('div:not(#dontselect)').wrap('<div class="wrapper" />');
```

It sorta works, but everything inside #dontselect also get wrapped in .wrapper classes. I want #dontselect and everything inside it to remain how they were. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add another `:not`:

```
$('div:not(#dontselect):not(#dontselect div)')
```

This excludes all `div` descendants of `#dontselect`.

Comment: That is work for most of elements but for HTML (:root), I searched and i found this useful solution if anyone need except some elements from :root selector. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3838758/select-the-div-but-not-the-link-inside-it-jquery-question

Answer (score 0):

do you need to wrap div childs?
to select only divs in body without their childs use

```
$('body > div:not(#dontselect)').wrapp('<div />');
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also do it in 3 steps

```
$('body')
   .find('div')             // step 1, find all divs
   .filter('#dontselect')     // step 2, add class 'no-wrapp'
      .addClass('no-wrapp')
         .find('div').addClass('no-wrapp')
   .end().end()
   .filter('div:not(.no-wrapp)').wrap('<div class="wrapper" />'); // step 3 wrap
```

then you can use the class 'no-wrap' for only the div's that do not wrap

Answer (score 0):

Try this :)

`$('div:not(#dontselect *)')`

Answer (score 0):

Another into the mix:

`$('div').filter(function(){ return !$(this).parents('#dontselect').length })`

Filters out all elements with the `#dontselect` parent.